# If E⊂X and if p is a limit point of E, then there is a sequence {pn} in E such that p=limn→∞pn.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $ E \subset X$ and let $p$ be a limit point of $E$. Prove that there is a sequence $ \{p_n\} $ in $E$ such that $p= \lim_{n\to\infty}p_n$.

This theorem is from page 48 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. I've tried to prove the statement. Is this approach okay?:

Suppose that there is no sequence $\{p_n\}$ in E such that $p=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n$.
Then $\exists \epsilon >0$ such that $\forall N$, $n \geq N$ implies that $d(p,p_n) \geq \epsilon$.
So $p_n \notin V_\epsilon (p)$ as $p_n \rightarrow p (n \geq N)$, where $V_\epsilon (p)$ is neighbourhood of point $p$ with radius $\epsilon$.
Then it is not true that all nbd's of p contain all but finitely many terms of $\{p_n \}$, because for $\epsilon$  above, the nbd of p, $V_\epsilon (p)$, does not contain infinitely many points of $p$.
Hence $p$ is not a limit point of E.

Therefore, by contraposition, if $E \subset X$, and $p$ is limit point of E, then 
there exists a sequence $ \{p_n \}$ in E such that $p= \lim_{n\to\infty} p_n$.

Comment: I don't understand your proof: if **there is no such sequence** $\;\{p_n\}\;$ , why then you continue to use it with $\;d(p,p_n)\ge\epsilon\;$ and etc.? This makes no sense...

Comment: It's a negation of the definition of a convergent sequence in E

Comment: @T J. No, it's not. It is only the negation that **a specific sequence** does not converge to $\;p\;$ ...and even then it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you said that there is no sequence of $E$ that converge to $p$ is wrong. To say that there is no sequence of $E$ that converge to $p$ is 
$$\exists \varepsilon>0: B(p,\varepsilon)\cap E=\emptyset,$$
where $B(x,r)=\{y\in X \mid d(x,y)<r\}$ (here, we let $d$ denote the metric of the metric space $X$).

Notice that your approach is weird (and unclear). If $p$ is a limit point of $E$, (I denote $E_p:=E\backslash \{p\}$) then
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, B(p,\varepsilon)\cap E_p\neq \emptyset,$$
in other words,
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N^*, \exists x_n\in E_p\cap B\left(p,\frac{1}{n}\right),$$
therefore $(x_n)$ is a sequence of $E$ that converges to $p$.

Comment: I see, you're right. I was assuming that {p_n} is a sequence in a metric space X. With this clarification, I used the definition of convergent sequences from Rudin's book, where a sequence in a metric space X is said to converge if there is a point p in X with the following property: for every $\epsilon >0$ there is an integer N such that $n \geq N$ implies that $d(p_n,p) < \epsilon$.